# how to create a custom web part page layout in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can anyone tell me how can I `create a web part page layout in sharepoint 2010 using Visual Studio` so that I can be able to deploy them to different servers?

And possibly add them in the Layout Template zone so that users can select them and create a web part page layout just like the OOTB pages.

Thank you

---

**EDIT 1:**

I am almost sovling my problem. This url helped me get going: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms916835.aspx. I will update this thread with the right answer once I have finished my work at hand. If in case I forget, please send remind me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no any predefined templates for this. I have one idea. Create a page any site and take the markup of that page from sharepoint designer. paste that markup into our visual studio page. Now deploy it as a site page. See this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/69b509cd-4865-4d9f-891f-5050d59e78b4). Now you can use it into different servers by deploying them. I hope this may some what useful.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Mihir, but this has to be added to the list of other web part pages list found unde \More Options\Page

Comment: Please look at my Edit 1 in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You create the custom page layout first and then add it to your solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: I mean you create it first in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: You can edit your answer, rather than commenting it. it makes it easier to read for others...

Comment: It is better to [edit] your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. All of this information can be edited into your question to make it easier for people to answer your question. If all of the information is contained in one block then people don't have to read all of the comments to discover all of the information. Once all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied & deleted